# How to capture audio on iPhone with PhoneGap?

Tags: iphone, cordova

I'm trying to learn how to use PhoneGap to create an application on the iPhone and I need to be able to capture audio by using the microphone.

I've looked at their documentation on how to Capture Audio found [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_media_capture_capture.md.html#CaptureAudioOptions)  but I can't seem to get it to work. There is a full example of code in the capture.

CaptureAudio section that I tried using, but it didn't seem record anything when I tried to test it on my iPhone. Is there something I need to add to the example code they have?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does anything happen at all when you try the demo code? In other words, you said it didn't seem to record, but did you get the recording UI at least? Did anything happen?

Comment: No, there's a screen with a button that says "Capture Audio" but tapping it does nothing.

Comment: Oh sorry - I misread you. So - what do you see in the Chrome Dev Tools console? Any error?

Comment: I didn't use the Chrome Dev Tools. But on Xcode there are no errors, but there is this warning:  'invokeString' is deprecated: Deprecated in Cordova 2.0. Use window.handleOpenURL(url instead. It is called when the app is launched through a custom scheme url.

Comment: OK - can you share (via Pastebin or a Gist) your exact code? Include just the HTML and JS.

Comment: Sure, it's the same as in the example, but here's a link from Pastebin of the index.html code http://pastebin.com/YgNZ045x#.

Comment: One issue is that the sample code does NOT wait for the deviceready event (http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready). All code that makes use of device stuff is supposed to wait for that to fire. I'd add that in. Secondly, I'd add a quick alert in captureAudio to ensure the button is correctly firing it.

Comment: Ok, so I've added the deviceready event and now the recording UI appears when I tap the capture audio button, so thank you! The documentation says that when the capture operation is finished, it will invoke the CaptureCB callback with an array of MediaFile objects describing each captured audio clip file. How do I access this audio clip file? Once I record and tap the Done button on the recording UI I return back to the original launch screen with the Capture Audio button and I'm unsure of where the recording is saved if it is saved at all. This is my updated code http://pastebin.com/jjAS1PaL.

Comment: I'd recommend the docs for MediaFile: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_media_capture_capture.md.html#MediaFile Notice it includes a fullPath value.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Xcode, make sure you have the cordova-2.3.0.js file in your index.html root directory, as this is where your html should be pointing to it.

If it is there, add some alerts in to it to make sure it's getting called.